The input field is automatically suggesting numbers, even though I have set autocomplete="off"
When i am open login screen, email input field automatiocally fillup with mobile number autofill in my Next.js project
see the image and see number autofill in email field, while login/signup.

as you can see, this is my login popup, where my input field type=email and even my autocomplete=off, but still it's showing the suggestion and it is number. the problem is that suggestion is automatically detected and additionaly type mismatched. it should be email for suggesting if it's suggest.


are you using chrome?

Even if you described with words, it's better to show your code

yes, code added @Mark

yes, i'm using crome browser @BagusTesa

@PratikRanpariya so, yeah, try the solutions on the link above. it seems chrome is a bit different on handling autocomplete attribute. there are quite some gotchas you have to check.

@PratikRanpariya, ok, thanks. But the code should be written as text, not as image
